# Compare two lists of different types using HashMap

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, hashmap, processing-efficiency

I have two classes:

```
public class AClass{

    String name;
    int id;
    int total;
}

public class BClass{
    String batchName;
    int id;
}
```

Now I have two lists:

```
List<AClass> aLst;
List<BClass> bLst;
```

Between these two list i need to check if `AClass.id==BClass.id`.
One way to achieve this is to have two ***for*** loops and compare. But this is not the efficient way.

Other way is by using `HashMap`. Traverse the `BClass` list and use the `BClass.id` as the key and the respective object as the value:

```
Map<int,BClass> map = new HashMap<int,BClass>();
List requiredLst <BClass> = new ArrayList<BClass>();
foreach(BClass b : bLst){
    map.put(BClass.id, b);
}

foreach(AClass a : aLst){
    BClass b = map.get(a.id);
    requiredLst.add(b);
}
```

Is this efficient way to compare?

Comment: You haven't sufficiently described the actual comparison procedure. What does the procedure return, a boolean? What if the 5th element in the first list has the same id as the 13th element in the second list?

Comment: Are you looking just for missing ids or for entire objects?

Comment: I am looking for all the objects of BClass in bLst having the same id's as that of the ids in the AClass objects ..

Comment: We can safely assume that IDs are unquie...

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier with a `Set<Integer>` to store the identifiers from `AClass`. Since `Set.contains()` is O(1) the total complexity will be O(n).

```
List<AClass> aLst = ...;
List<BClass> bLst = ...;

Set<Integer> ids = aLst.stream()
    .map(AClass::getId)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
List<BClass> required = bLst.stream()
    .filter(b -> ids.contains(b.getId()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However for small lists the cost of creating additional `Set` and boxing identifiers into `Integer` might outweigh the benefit of reduced number of iterations.